# My SQL Server procedure always return -1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm coding a web app with ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework.

I call the procedure like this in C#:

```
var result = context.EditTechInfo(user.id, user.telephone, user.email);
```

Where `context` is the Entity Framework instance.

I have a procedure that always returns -1, but it execute the `UPDATE`it is supposed to do. I have tried to return my value using `SELECT` instead of `RETURN` but to no avail.

Here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EditTechInfo
    (@tech INT,
     @telephone CHAR(10),
     @email VARCHAR(64))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @result  INT = 0

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Techs WHERE id = @tech AND statut = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Techs
        SET telephone = @telephone, email = @email
        WHERE id = @tech

        SET @result = 1
    END
    --ELSE
    --BEGIN
        --SET @result = -1
    --END

    SELECT @result
END
```

Even if the part where -1 could be the returned value is commented...

I know that if a procedure returns -1 it means that there was an error, but I cannot figure where nor why...

## ----EDIT-------

As asked in the comment, here is what EF generated:

```
public virtual int EditTechInfo(Nullable<int> tech, string telephone, string email)
        {
            var techParameter = tech.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("tech", tech) :
                new ObjectParameter("tech", typeof(int));

            var telephoneParameter = telephone != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("telephone", telephone) :
                new ObjectParameter("telephone", typeof(string));

            var emailParameter = email != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("email", email) :
                new ObjectParameter("email", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("EditTechInfo", techParameter, telephoneParameter, emailParameter);
        }
```

Comment: What is  your `IF EXISTS` expression returns ?

Comment: @Shyju From what i deduct, it returns true, because the update statement get executed

Comment: How is `EditTechInfo` defined? I'm willing to bet that EF is screwing something up, either directly or because of a mismatch between it and your stored procedure.

Comment: You can use `BEGIN TRY`... `BEGIN CATCH` to caught any exception if you suspected an exception occurred, or if you really want to use return value for the procedure, place `@result` parameter marked as `INT OUTPUT` and pass it to result variable in model/controller code.

Comment: your ordering of sp and calling from c# code is different ..Please take care of it

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash A slight typo, sorry for that.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I edited my question to show you the `EF` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto) suggested that I use `OUTPUT` parameter. I've read a bit more on [the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter(v=vs.110).aspx). I decided to use this approach and it worked.

I added a new paramter, notice the `OUTPUT` parameter

Here is the modified `PROCEDURE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EditTechInfo
(
    @tech           INT,
    @telephone      CHAR(10),
    @email          VARCHAR(64),
    @result         INT OUTPUT --- this is new
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @result = 0;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Techs WHERE id = @tech AND statut = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Techs
            SET telephone = @telephone, email = @email
        WHERE id = @tech

        SET @result = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = -1
    END

    RETURN @result -- I don't know if i have to actually return it since it is an output param
END
```

Here is how you call it inside `c#`: 
**(note that it is an over simplified code)**

The big addon here is that I changed the `result` variable type to `ObjectParameter`. After that I had to retrieve the `Value` of my result. I casted it into an `int` otherwise it is a simple `Object`.

```
public int GetEditTechInfoValue(int id, string telephone, string email)
        {
            var result = new ObjectParameter("result", 0);
            var type = result.ParameterType;

            // This is an instance of my EntityFramework entities...you get the point
            context.EditTechInfo(id, telephone, email, result);

            return (int)result.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code .it will work on EF 6+

```
String spQuery = String.Format("EditTechInfo {0},'{1}','{2}'", 0, "telephone  ", "email");
int result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(spQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ah yes, the answer to every EF problem is pretty much "pretend you are using Dapper".

Comment: This is a work around, but I still do not know how to correct my error and why it is always returning -1 though

Answer (score -1):

The are getting -1 because of the `SET NOCOUNT ON`.  Either remove it or specify `SET NOCOUNT OFF` to get the count of rows affected by the proc.

Note that the widespread use of  `SET NOCOUNT ON` has it's roots in classic ADODB, where the rowcounts (actually DONE_IN_PROC TDS messages) confused applications that were not expecting them.  This is a non-issue with SqlClient because the API plays nicer from a development perspective.

Comment: This affect the return value?

Comment: No, `SET NOCOUNT ON` will not affect the return value. And using it is a good idea because it can reduce network traffic. http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/How-NOCOUNT-affects-ADO.NET

Comment: @JonathanAllen, I agree `SET NOCOUNT` it won't affect the return value of the stored procedure but it will affect the value returned by SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery.  I'm not much of an EF guy but I thought that is what was actually returned rather than the stored procedure return value.